# How to print using a zebra printer in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i need to print a bill. I intend to print this bill using a Zebra printer. I have never done this before. So i have no idea how to do this. Any help would be appretiated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: u have to download first zebra api for android

Comment: are you fix your problem

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Zebra has posted a complete tutorial on how to print with the ZSDK API on Android: https://km.zebra.com/resources/sites/ZEBRA/content/live/WHITE_PAPERS/0/WH62/en_US/AndroidSDK_Java_GettingStarted_WH.pdf#xml=https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=answeropen&type=open&searchid=1360598145375&answerid=16777216&iqaction=6&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkm.zebra.com%2Fresources%2Fsites%2FZEBRA%2Fcontent%2Flive%2FWHITE_PAPERS%2F0%2FWH62%2Fen_US%2FAndroidSDK_Java_GettingStarted_WH.pdf&highlightinfo=8388708,9,19.  Furthermore, their knowledgebase contains a lot of sample code that should get you in the right direction: http://km.zebra.com.  In general, Stackoverflow should be able to help if you have more specific questions!

Comment: thanks for the link....But whenever i try to connect to the printer, a dialog appears asking for the passcode....i reset the passcode to 0000....but i have to enter the code every time i try to connect to the printer....how can i pair the printer with my android device so that i will not ask me to enter that code again and again?
Thanks....

Comment: You should attempt to pair outside of the application.  In most cases, once you pair from the Android settings area, the application should not ask for the Bluetooth pin again.

Also, check the Zebra SDK for updates.  I believe a revision/update is coming out soon!

Comment: link not working :( However article may be found here: https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=answers&startover=y&question_box_status=changed&question_box=android&restrict=

Comment: Is there an Android print service available?  I want to be able to print a web page from Google Chrome to my ZQ520 printer.

Comment: guys it's 2019 and I am trying to find the link to this, can somebody help me ?

Comment: can we print the RFID tag using android?